# Summarize (counts) by column efficiently

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, summarize

I have a big table similar to `datadf` with 3000 thousand columns and rows, I saw some methods to obtain my expected summary in stack overflow ([Frequency of values per column in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44295144/frequency-of-values-per-column-in-table/52283354#52283354)), but even the fastest is very slow for my table. EDIT: thx to comments, several methods are currently satisfactory.

## Creating example data

```
library(data.table)

datadf <- data.frame(var1 = rep(c("T","A","G","C"), each = 3), var2 = rep(c("A","T","G","C"), each = 3), var3 = rep('-', 12), stringsAsFactors = F )
datadf <- datadf[sample(1:nrow(datadf), 1000, T),sample(1:ncol(datadf), 1000, T)]
dataDT <- as.data.table(datadf)
dataDT[1:7,1:20]
#    var2 var2.1 var3 var3.1 var1 var3.2 var2.2 var3.3 var2.3 var1.1 var3.4 var2.4 var1.2 var3.5 var2.5 var2.6 var1.3 var3.6 var2.7 var1.4
# 1:    T      T    -      -    A      -      T      -      T      A      -      T      A      -      T      T      A      -      T      A
# 2:    G      G    -      -    G      -      G      -      G      G      -      G      G      -      G      G      G      -      G      G
# 3:    T      T    -      -    A      -      T      -      T      A      -      T      A      -      T      T      A      -      T      A
# 4:    C      C    -      -    C      -      C      -      C      C      -      C      C      -      C      C      C      -      C      C
# 5:    C      C    -      -    C      -      C      -      C      C      -      C      C      -      C      C      C      -      C      C
# 6:    A      A    -      -    T      -      A      -      A      T      -      A      T      -      A      A      T      -      A      T
# 7:    T      T    -      -    A      -      T      -      T      A      -      T      A      -      T      T      A      -      T      A
```

## Benchmark

```
library(tidyverse)
library(microbenchmark)
lev<-unique(unlist(datadf))

microbenchmark(
  #base EDITED based on comment @ fishtank
  sapply(datadf, function(x) table(factor(x, levels=lev, ordered=TRUE))), #modified based on comment

  #tidyverse EDITED based on comment @AntoniosK
  datadf %>% gather() %>% count(key, value) %>% spread(key, n, fill = 0L), # based on comment

  #data.table
  dcast(melt(dataDT, id=1:1000, measure=1:1000)[,1001:1002][, `:=` (Count = .N), by=.(variable,value)], value ~ variable ,
        value.var = "value", fun.aggregate = length),

  # Answer from @bk18
  # myDcast<-
  dcast.data.table(
    melt.data.table(dataDT, measure.vars = colnames(dataDT))[, .N, .(variable, value)],
    value ~ variable,
    value.var = "N",
    fill = 0
  ),
  times=1
)
```

## Result

```
myDcast[,1:20]

#    value var2 var2.1 var3 var3.1 var1 var3.2 var2.2 var3.3 var2.3 var1.1 var3.4 var2.4 var1.2 var3.5 var2.5 var2.6 var1.3 var3.6 var2.7
# 1:     -    0      0 1000   1000    0   1000      0   1000      0      0   1000      0      0   1000      0      0      0   1000      0
# 2:     A  254    254    0      0  280      0    254      0    254    280      0    254    280      0    254    254    280      0    254
# 3:     C  230    230    0      0  230      0    230      0    230    230      0    230    230      0    230    230    230      0    230
# 4:     G  236    236    0      0  236      0    236      0    236    236      0    236    236      0    236    236    236      0    236
# 5:     T  280    280    0      0  254      0    280      0    280    254      0    280    254      0    280    280    254      0    280



                              min          lq        mean      median          uq         max neval
   sapply-table          89.77978    89.77978    89.77978    89.77978    89.77978    89.77978     1
   gather-count-spread  849.83078   849.83078   849.83078   849.83078   849.83078   849.83078     1
   dcast-melt         19938.71910 19938.71910 19938.71910 19938.71910 19938.71910 19938.71910     1
   data.table @bk18      46.92746    46.92746    46.92746    46.92746    46.92746    46.92746     1
```

Comment: Maybe this will make the `tidyverse` approach faster `datadf %>%
  gather() %>%
  count(key, value) %>%
  spread(key, n, fill = 0L)`

Comment: No idea about that. Haven't checked :) Just wanted to provide an alternative `tidyverse` solution.

Comment: 3000 columns and 3000 rows is pretty small. This takes under a  second already? If you're doing it many times (and I guess you shouldn't be), just keep your data in long/melted form and use `table` ... `mDT = melt(dataDT[, r := .I], id="r"); table(mDT[, c("value", "variable")])`

Comment: `levels=unique(unlist(datadf))` is called multiple times in your `sapply`. would be more efficient to calculate it once and store.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Frequency of values per column in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44295144/frequency-of-values-per-column-in-table)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is about double the speed of the data.table method you provided, and should scale very well with the size of the dataset:

```
setDT(datadf)
dcast.data.table(
  melt.data.table(datadf, measure.vars = colnames(datadf))[, .N, .(variable, value)], 
  value ~ variable,
  value.var = "N",
  fill = 0
)
```

I'd be interested to see the benchmarks for your full dataset, because not all of these methods will scale similarly.

Comment: Or the OP could just do it in cpp and avoid all this :)